# XSTL - maintain sequence

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an the input xml as:

```
<group>
    <item>
    <id>item 1</id>
    <CategoryName>blue</CategoryName>
    <id>item 2</id>
    <CategoryName>orange</CategoryName>
    <id>item 3</id>
     <CategoryName>green</CategoryName>
</item>
</group>
```

and I want to transform it to

```
<group>
<item>
    <itemNode><id>item 1</id><itemNode>
    <Color>blue</Color>
    <itemNode><id>item 2</id><itemNode>
    <Color>orange</Color>
    <itemNode><id>item 3</id><itemNode>
     <Color>green</Color>
</item>
```

When I use xpath, it shows itemNodes tags first and then Color tags but not in the sequence the data was orignally in.

Any ideas how I can transform but still maintain the sequence?

Comment: can you post the xslt you got?

Comment: So, you "forgot" the main data???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="item">
<group>
  <item>
    <xsl:for-each select="id">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
      <itemNode><id><xsl:value-of select="."/></id></itemNode>
      <color><xsl:value-of select="../CategoryName[$pos]"/></color>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </item>
</group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: xiaoyi, thanks! you solution work, but one thing I forgot to mention is the the id and CategoryName could be repeatitive like this: <group>
    <item>
    <id>item 1</id>
    <id>item 1.1</id>
    <CategoryName>blue</CategoryName>
    <id>item 2</id>
     <id>item 2</id>
      <id>item 2</id>
    <CategoryName>orange</CategoryName>
    <id>item 3</id>
    <id>item 3.1</id>
     <CategoryName>green</CategoryName>
</item>
</group>